# I have defined a vector according to a certain rule. How do I define a function that outputs the vector?

Tags: r

the rule is: `for(i in 1:10){v[i]=f(q,m)}`. f(q,m) is a function that generates random outputs in an interval according to the inputs q, m. 'v' is the vector.

After specifying the components of v that way, I can type v, and return the vector. What I would like to be able to do is define a function that takes the inputs q,m and returns the vector, v.

The reason is eventually I want to be able to graph the mean of v, ranging over the variable q. but i need a function that returns v first, i think. So any advice on how to define such a function would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does `runif` already do what you want?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you pose a problem it helps to provide us with a minimally reproducible example as described [(HERE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  When you give code you should define what everything is since we don't know what f is.  This makes your question useful for others searching the thread and not just specific to you.  It also helps to give us an example of what the output should be.

Answer (score 2):

Generating values is elegantly done using the apply family of functions. `vapply` is lesser known, but more efficient than `sapply`, so I promote it here. The `numeric(1)` specifies what the result of `f` is expected to be:

```
# Emulating your function f
f <- function(q, m) runif(1, q, m)

# Generator function
g <- function(n=10, q, m) vapply(seq_len(n), function(i) f(q, m), numeric(1))

# Try it out
q <- 3
m <- 5
v <- g(10, q, m)

# or, if f is defined as above, simplify to:
v <- runif(10, q, m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly following your code:

```
makeVector <- function(q, m) { 
  v <- c()
  for (i in 1:10) {
    v[i] <- f(q, m)
  }
  v
}
```

Or, more elegant:

```
makeVector <- function(q, m) sapply(1:10, function(q, m) f(q, m))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably equivalent to the solutions offered (and doesn't fully address the missing details) but have you tried?

```
Vf <- Vectorize(f)
```